# You know how to turn on (the) printer(s)!

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

> You know how to turn on (the) printer(s)!

A child has turned on a computer and you are making a mark. It is the printer, but you are not limiting your meaning to this occasion and you mean printers in general. Would "the" printer convey this meaning?

Comment: If you mean printers in general, you should say *printers* or *a printer*. If you use the definite article *the* printer, you're referring to a printer in particular or the concept of a printer (e.g. The printer allows you to output digital data onto paper.).

Comment: @Sander, thanks. I know the concept you are talking about, but do you understand my concept?

Comment: Well, in this case I would either use *a printer* or *printers*, since you're talking about the machine in general and not about one in particular nor the concept of a printer.

Comment: If you say 'the printer' or 'the printers' in this sentence, it would mean that the child is able to turn on the specific printer or printers in that room, but is not necessarily able to turn on any other printers. He only knows how to turn on those printers. If you say he is able to turn on 'a printer' or 'printers', he knows how that type of machine works and is able to turn on the machine in general (this includes any printers outside of the building or room you're talking about in this context).

Answer (score -1):

When you are refering to a printer, for example one in your home you would say "the printer" this is refering to ONE specific printer if you wanted to refer to multiple specific printers you would say "the printer**s**". If you wanted to talk about any printer in general (for example: any printer) you would say "I can turn on a printer".

Trevor

Comment: You don't necessarily refer to one specific printer when using 'the'. For example, in the following sentence, 'the' doesn't refer to one single animal: The tiger is a striped animal.

Comment: Thanks, Trevor. I have to ask you if you are a native since Sander is asking a question relating to my OP.  (Can't make a confindent comment as you never know where "the" bomb will blow)

Comment: @joeKim If you are asking if I am a native speaker, then yes I am. And in the sentence "you never know where **the** bomb will blow" it still follows my answer you are referring to a specific item.

Comment: @Sander When you use "the" in that sentence it has a totally different meaning, you are refering to a species not an object. Saying "The tiger is a striped animal." is like saying "The human is smart." it is not a correct use of the. Instead you could say " Tigers are striped animals" or in my example "Humans are smart".

Comment: @TrevorClarke, thanks. Then, it should have been bombs and turn on printers with "the" optional, is it?

Comment: As I said before "the" changes what you are refering to ie if you wanted to say you know how to turn on printers you would say "I know how to turn on printer" but lets say you bought a new printer and you learned how to turn it on you would say "the printer".

Comment: @TrevorClarke The use of 'the' that I wrote about in my comment above, IS correct. Indeed, it does not have the same meaning, it refers to the concept of the tiger and not one tiger in particular. However, the meaning being different does not imply that my sentence was incorrect. I was just trying to explain that there are more types of usage for the definite article than just referring to a specific thing or person.

Comment: @TrevorClarke. Thanks again. You have written turn on "printer" without any articles to mean printers in general. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, at least that is one method to do it.... If you really wanted to use plural to refer to printers in general you could also say "I know how to turn on printers"... both work... neither are better.

Comment: @TrevorClarke thanks. Then how far this words without articles to mean general can go? Can this be applied to everything? For example, I like table(tables), car(cars), train(trains), sky; use computer(computers) when working; key(keys) to lock door(door); etc. this is new info to me.

Comment: @JoeKim No, for singular count nouns, you almost always have to use an article (a/an, the) or a determiner (this/that), possessive (my, Sally's), or something else. You can't say *You know you how to turn on printer.* Well, you can say it, but it is not in accord with standard grammar.